# Sum Expression Access Query for Completed Fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to write a code that will sum the prices of all the orders that come up when I fill out the query. For example, if I enter the ID range 1-60, I want there to be a sum column created that then sums up all the prices of ID's 1-60.

I thought it would be simple enough to just create a SUM(.....) AS Exp 1, but it tells me that there is a problem with the ID and aggregate function.

My current code looks like this:

```
SELECT table.ID, table.Price, SUM(table.Price) AS Exp 1 
FROM table
WHERE table.ID BETWEEN StartID AND EndID
```

Thank you for any help

EDIT: I should've specified this earlier, but I want to be able to see the individual prices, as well as a new column with the sum of all these prices. I plan on adding some more columns of data into the table later on.

Comment: Remove `table.ID` and `table.Price` from the `SELECT`.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Comment: Use Group by for aggregate function `SELECT table.ID, table.Price, SUM(table.Price) AS Exp 1 
FROM table
WHERE table.ID BETWEEN StartID AND EndID Group by table.ID, table.Price`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the sum over all the rows, then only include that in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT SUM(table.Price) AS Exp1 
FROM table 
WHERE table.ID BETWEEN StartID AND EndID
```

Comment: This is where it gets more complicated, I forgot to mention it and will go back and edit. But I need to see the individual prices as well as the total sum of prices, due to the fact that there is some additional important information incorporated into the price.

Comment: @nola94 . . . You should not change the meaning of a question after it has been answered.  That can invalidate answers, which draws downvotes -- and is hence rude.  You should ask another question instead.